# Display the Last Updated Date of a Posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the last update date of a post in WordPress, i can find this code and i must put it in function.php

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
$custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
} 

$custom_content .= $content;
return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

It's working but the problem that i also have update date displayed on pages, portfolios, ....

How can i limit the display of updated date just on post for the blog ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition to check the post type:

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
    $u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
    $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
        if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400 && is_singular('post')) { 
            $updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
            $updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
            $custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
        } 

    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
    }
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

[is_singular()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) queries for a single post and takes the post type as an argument.

Comment: Is this compatible with php8.0? I receive an error message which is: Warning: Undefined variable $custom_content in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child-theme/functions.php on line 108

Comment: To get of this warning, you can initialize the variable with `$custom_content = ''`